# Running powershell Script from Python (password decryption)

Tags: python, windows, powershell, subprocess, stdout

I am writing a python script to decrypt password by calling Powershell functions:

```
import subprocess
keypwd = "BoFaTnpCv0XYrVxND8mi"
pwd= "76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8AFUAMQA5AHEAWABvAFMAdwBHAEQASQAyAHcAVABJAHMAbwBKAHAASwBBAEEAPQA9AHwANAA4ADAANwA0ADAANQA5ADEAMgBlADkAZABjAGEAZQA5ADUAZQAyADcAZQBmADAAZAA1AGQAMAAxAGYAMAA0ADQAMQA5ADcAOAAxAGMAYgBlAGYAMwAwADcANwBhADMAMwA0AGMAOQAzAGYAOQA0AGQAMwAwAGMAYgA3ADMAMQA4AGQAYgBlAGUANAAyADQAOQAzADcAMABkADQAMABmADAAMABmADAAYwBkADQAMwBkADMAMABkAGUAOABjAGIA"

POWERSHELL = 'powershell -c "{0}"'
KEY_DECRYPT_CMD = '''Function KeySet {{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess,ConfirmImpact = 'None')]
    param([string]$string)
    $length = $string.length
    $pad = 32-$length
    $encoding = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
    $bytes = $encoding.GetBytes($string + "0" * $pad)
    return $bytes
}}

Function DecryptData ($data, $key) {{
    $data | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key |
    ForEach-Object {{[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($_))}}
}}


$setkey = KeySet '{key}';
DecryptData -data '{pwd}' -key $setkey
'''

cmd1 = POWERSHELL.format(KEY_DECRYPT_CMD.format(pwd=pwd, key = keypwd))
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
```

If I run independently only first function (`KeySet`) in Python, I am getting the following output:

```
b'66\r\n111\r\n70\r\n97\r\n84\r\n110\r\n112\r\n67\r\n118\r\n48\r\n88\r\n89\r\n114\r\n86\r\n120\r\n78\r\n68\r\n56\r\n109\r\n105\r\n48\r\n'
```

which is the same output I get in Powershell (though without `\r\n` parts).

However, the second function (`DecryptData`) is not working when it is called from Python.
The error message I get is the following:

```
b'ConvertTo-SecureString : 
The specified key is not valid. Valid key length settings are either 128 bits, 192 bits, or \r\n256 bits.
\r\nAt line:12 char:13\r\n+   $data | ConvertTo-SecureString -key $key |\r\n+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], PSArgumentException\r\n    
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCo \r\n   mmand\r\n \r\n'
```

The same script works without any problems in Powershell.

I think the issue occurs because the key is not passed in the correct form in the `DecryptData` function, but I am not able to find the solution.

Is there a way to make this code work?

Comment: Using encryption for passwords means the passwords are not secure. If you can decrypt them then so can any other hacker. You should use one of the HASH algorithms to create secure passwords.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you're running? Problem is missing padding - the key output from the first function should be 32 bytes in length, but the string you've posted only has a single byte of padding, for a total length of 21

Comment: @OldBoy - I need this for one particular task, basically to mimic what has already been deployed in PS.
@MathiasR.Jessen - thanks for your comment. 
In the code, you can see that zeros are padded:
`$pad = 32-$length`, and `$encoding.GetBytes($string + "0" * $pad)`.
As I mentioned, the code is working fine in Powershell.